# Returning SQL version using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm struggling to return a SQL version using C#, I'm new to SQL programming so any help would be great. I'm getting various errors but below is my latest attempt.

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string strSqlVersion = SQLVersion();
    MessageBox.Show(strSqlVersion);
}

private void sqlversion(string sqlver)
{
    OdbcConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        conn = getConnection(comboBoxDatabase.Text);
        string strSql = "SELECT @@VERSION";
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(strSql, conn);
        string returnvalue = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return returnvalue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){ }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some of the various errors you're getting?

Comment: Also, the code doesn't even make sense. Presumably it's supposed to be a call to `sqlversion(string)` rather than just `string strSqlVersion = SQLVersion()`.

Comment: I apologize, my comment about the OP code was probably out of line and has been deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
private string SQLVersion()
{
    string version = "";
    try
    {
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("..."))
        using (OdbcCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cn.Open();
            cm.CommandText = "SELECT @@Version";
            version = cm.ExecuteScalar() as string;
        }
    }
    catch (OdbcException) { }
    return version;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like:

```
var dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ConnectionStringSettings.ProviderName);
conn = dbProviderFactory .CreateConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ...
conn.Open();
string serverVersion = conn.ServerVersion;
```

This is database-agnostic.

Comment: This is just an optimized refactoring of a small piece of the code (the only part of the posted code that actually would work, assuming his getConnection method is sound), and doesn't address any of the actual problems in the code.

Answer (score 5):

Your method is declared void, change it to String:

```
private string sqlversion(string sqlver)
{
    OdbcConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        conn = getConnection(comboBoxDatabase.Text);
        string strSql = "SELECT @@VERSION";
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(strSql, conn);
        string returnvalue = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return returnvalue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){ }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: And see @Rubens Farias post about "Using"

Comment: This does not nearly address all of the problems in the code.

Comment: Hi thanks, When using MessageBox.Show(sqlversion().ToString()); I get the error "No overload for method 'sqlversion' take 0 arguments", where am I going wrong?

Comment: due to the way the method is declared, it requires a string parameter, so do MessageBox.Show(sqlversion("").ToString()); or removed string sqlver from the declaration

Comment: Also, since you should at that point be returning a string from your `sqlversion` method, you don't need to `.ToString()` it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, which is much shorter, is to use the [SMO library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx) like this:

```
var con = 
    new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection("MyServerName");
Debug.Print(con.ServerVersion.ToString());
```

On mine (SQL Server 2005) this prints "9.0".

Comment: This is just an optimized refactoring of a small piece of the code (the only part of the posted code that actually would work, assuming his getConnection method is sound), and doesn't address any of the actual problems in the code.

Comment: No, it's an alternate solution to what he's trying to do.  All you're doing by posting comments like this to every answer but your own is making yourself look like a jackass.

Comment: The problem is that it's an alternate solution to the only part of the OP code that worked... see the OP comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065605/returning-sql-version-using-c/2065646#2065646 Chris Haas's answer.

Comment: The guy is trying to get the version of SQL Server.  This is code that gets the version of SQL Server.  I'm not sure how much simpler I can make it for you, md5sum.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string strSqlVersion = sqlversion();
    MessageBox.Show(strSqlVersion);
}

private string sqlversion()
{

    try
    {
        using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(comboBoxDatabase.Text))
        {
            string strSql = "SELECT @@VERSION";
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(strSql, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string returnvalue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                return returnvalue;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OdbcException ex){ }
}
```

C# is a case sensitive language, so I've fixed the casing of your method call. Also, you  cannot return a string from a void method. I've also declared your OdbcConnection as `new` and initialized it with what I presume is an appropriate connection string from a `ComboBox`.

EDIT: I've also added `using` blocks to ensure proper disposal of your `OdbcCommand` and `OdbcConnection` objects. Your method call to `sqlversion` also included a parameter, but none was specified, so I've removed the parameter.

EDIT 2: Modified the catch to only handle (and ignore) only an `OdbcException`.